# Organize data in CSV into multiple lists in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm working with a large CSV file with two columns - IP address and a Group name. Below is an example data:

```
ip          group
192.168.1.1 A
192.168.1.2 B
192.168.1.3 C
192.168.1.4 A
192.168.1.5 B
192.168.1.6 C
```

I need to organize the data into separate lists of IPs, based on the Group name. Something like this: `sorted_data = (A, B, C)`,
where 
`A = (192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.4), B = (192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.5)` and so forth.

The whole file is about 10K records with about 20 unique groups. Please help!

Comment: What have you tried? Does it have to be pure python or can you use `pandas`?

Comment: Pandas is a bit over my head, but I'm all for it if that would make it easier. I'm trying to learn.

Comment: Getting KeyError: 'group' in _get_grouper. Any idea why that happens>

Comment: @user1781482 Is it with regards to the pandas solution? Possibly an error with your columns? Print `df.columns` and paste the output here. Also, please ping me so I can see your comment. Use @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ  to do so.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Is there a way to get this to work, if there are other columns in the csv? I still need only the ip and group, while the other columns can be ignored.

Comment: Add `usecols=['ip', 'group']` as an attribute to `pd.read_csv`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I started a new question, trying to do the reverse of this. This might be up your alley :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820888/pandas-data-to-csv-in-python-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're open to using `pandas` (as you indicated in your comment), this is how you'd do it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=',')
dct = df.groupby('group').ip.apply(lambda x: x.tolist()).to_dict()

print(dct)
{'A': ['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.4'],
 'B': ['192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.5'],
 'C': ['192.168.1.3', '192.168.1.6']}
```

Access `dct`'s values to get your IP list by group.

Answer (score 0):

using the classic `re.split` you could do:

```
import re

data="ip\tgroup\n'192.168.178.1'\tA\n'192.168.178.2'\tB\n'192.168.178.3'\tC\n'192.168.178.4'\tD\n'192.168.178.5'\tE\n'192.168.178.6'\tA\n"

lines=re.split('\n',data)[1:-1]
sorted_data={}
for line in lines:
  splt=re.split('\t',line)
  ip,group=splt[0],splt[1]
  try:
    sorted_data[group].append(ip)
  except KeyError:
    sorted_data[group]=[ip]
print(sorted_data)
```